# js file loading only for first time - in angularjs : Making the ckeditor visible for first time only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor

I am loading the .js file like this

`<script type="text/javascript" src="public/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`

The Ckeditor is appearing only at the first time,  if i navigate to other page, and came back to original page the ckeditor is not working..

I tried to load the `ckeditor.js` in the `index.html` -> My main file which loads all the .js files and even seperately in the `add.html` where i use the ckeditor

`<textarea class="ckeditor" name="receipeBody" ></textarea>`

i.e.,

```
public/app/js/angular.min.js
public/app/app/app.js
public/app/app/data.js
public/app/app/directives.js
public/app/app/authCtrl.js
```

I tried to load in the Main Page and even in `add.html` page.

It works only the first time, if i navigate to some other page and return to `add.html` page the ckeditor is not loading.. it is just showing the regular textarea..

I even tried to load the `.js` file after the `add.html` is fully loaded..

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("public/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js");
});
```

Still, i can't able to see the ckeditor in the second view..

**What is the mistake i am doing and How can i make the ckeditor to be visible even after first visit of the page...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

The best way to set the CKEditor configuration is in-page, when creating editor instances. This method lets you avoid modifying the original distribution files in the CKEditor installation folder, making the upgrade task easier.

In-page settings can be passed to any of the editor instance creation functions, namely `CKEDITOR.replace` and `CKEDITOR.appendTo`

```
<textarea id="ckeditor"></textarea>

    <script>

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor', {

            height : '500px',
    removePlugins: 'bidi,font,forms,flash,horizontalrule,iframe,justify,table,tabletools,smiley,Paste from Word',
    removeButtons: 'Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Image,Paste,Print,Templates,Preview,NewPage,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Replace,About,Language,Save,PageBreak,Scayt,ShowBlocks',
    format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre;address'
} );

        </script>
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration